# Positioning a UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView on top of the camera preview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, cameraoverlayview

I want to add an overlay to my UIImagePickerController, but I only need it to cover the camera preview, and not the camera controls at the top or bottom. I cannot find anywhere a way to do this as the top/bottom controls heights are different on every device. I've seen it done before on other apps. Any guidance is appreciated.

```swift
imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            
let overlay = UIView()
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView!.addSubview(overlay)
// This is using a UIView extension to constrain my views. It's as simple as it looks.
overlay.anchor(top: imagePicker.cameraOverlayView!.topAnchor, left: imagePicker.cameraOverlayView!.leftAnchor, bottom: imagePicker.cameraOverlayView!.bottomAnchor, right: imagePicker.cameraOverlayView!.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want this translucent UIView to fill the red area only. I have no problem creating the frame to be 3:4 but it won't position correctly on the Y axis. `imagePicker.cameraOverlayView!.centerYAnchor` is the same as the device's centerYAnchor.

[image: UIImagePickerController]

Comment: It might be easier to make your own custom camera with AVFoundation - https://medium.com/@barbulescualex/making-a-custom-camera-in-ios-ea44e3087563

Comment: @aheze I will keep that in mind if there does not end up being a solution to this question. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution. Using view debugger you can inspect the view hierarchy. Now add the view into the child `camera view port controller`

```
imagePicker = CustomPicker()
imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


class CustomPicker: UIImagePickerController {
    let overlay = UIView()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let camController = children.first?.children.first?.children.first, overlay.superview == nil {
            overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
            camController.view.addSubview(overlay)
            overlay.addPinConstraints(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func addPinConstraints(top: CGFloat? = nil, left: CGFloat? = nil, bottom: CGFloat? = nil, right: CGFloat? = nil) {
        guard let parent = superview else { return }
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let left = left {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.leadingAnchor, constant: left).isActive = true
        }
        if let right = right {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.trailingAnchor, constant: -right).isActive = true
        }
        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.topAnchor, constant: top).isActive = true
        }
        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.bottomAnchor, constant: -bottom).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the view inspector,
here child -> child -> child is the camera view port
[image]

Comment: I never thought to look in the view debugger... I was scratching my head for weeks trying to find where the subview showing the camera preview was to be found. I appreciate you taking the time to find this for me and I hope you enjoy your 50 points. Thanks man.